# Why does the "j" recognize the change in range, while the "i" does not?

Tags: python, for-loop, range

I'm working on some code where I have a situation which is similar to the code provided below.  It seems that in the second for loop, the change in the value of num is being recognized, while it is not in the value of the first for loop.  Why not, and how would I write this in a way that it would recognize it?

```
num=3
for i in range(num):
    for j in range(num):
        print(i, j)
        if num<5:
            num=num+1
```

The code begin as I would expect (0, 0), (0, 1) etc., but ends on (2, 4), as the j has reached the end of its range.  I don't understand why the first for loop doesn't know that num has been updated.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are expecting your for-loop to behave as a while-loop.

Let's write a slightly simpler example to see what is going on.

```
num = 5
for j in range(num):
    print(j)
    if j == 3:
        num = num + 1
```

#### Output

```
0
1
2
3
4
  <--- No 5
```

It seems you expected the behaviour of the above to be equivalent to the following snippet of code.

```
num = 5
j = 0
while j < num:
    print(j)
    if j == 3:
        num += 1
    j += 1
```

#### Output

```
0
1
2
3
4
5  <-- updating num added a value in the output
```

## for-loop vs while-loop

The fundamental difference between a for-loop and a while-loop is that a while-loop runs as long as its condition is true and it *reevaluates* the condition at every iteration. Meanwhile, the for-loop loops over the items in an iterable object (in that case a `range`), the iterable *is not reevaluated* at each operation.

## `range` object

Let's have a look at another example which explains why the iterable `range(num)` is not updated when `num` is incremented.

```
num = 5
r = range(num)
print(r) # range(0, 5)

num += 1
print(r) # still range(0, 5)
```

When calling `range(num)`, an iterable is created. It receives the value `5` as upper bound and does not care at all about the name `num`. As you can see, when `num` is updated, the object `r` is not affected. Why would it? it was given the value `5` and it's all it cares about.

## Back to your code

If the iterable of a for-loop *is not reevaluated*, why is it that the inner-loop is not always the same then?

Well, precisely because the inner-loop runs at every iteration. At every iteration of the outer loop, a new object `range(num)` is created for the inner loop and since `num` has been updated by then, the newly created `range` is not identical to the initial one.

Answer (score 0):

‘range(num)‘ is evaluated only once, not at each iteration. So it is equivalent to

```
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(num):
        # do something with i and j
```

Comment: Not exactly, on sample code, the line `for j in range(num):` will be reevaluated on the next loop of `i`

Answer (score 0):

```
def main():
    num=3
    for i in range(num):
        # Exiting nested for-loop causes range(num) to be re-evaluated
        for j in range(num):
            print(i, j)
            if num < 5:
                num=num+1

    # Now that we have exited the first for-loop,
    # range(num) is re-evaluated and 0,1,2,3,4 is printed
    for i in range(num):
        print(i)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

num value is locked when for loop is called. The value of num is updated only when it is called not while executing.